# Is it possible to customize a table's field values (pages) with Meteor-pages?

Tags: javascript, meteor, pagination

I was doing pagination on my Meteor app "the old way" (updating a session variable that works as a [starting point for my cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)) when I came across @alethes' [Meteor-Pages](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages).

I tried it with my Meteor app (which uses [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router)) and works fine provided I just to display a table with the values of the fields of my documents. I have been trying to display something different in the table (customizing these values) and I can't find a way to make it work.

From the documentation, all you need in your template is

```
<template name="collection-name">
    {{> pages}} <!-- this displays a table with your records -->
    {{> pagesNav}}  <!-- navigation bar-->
</template>
```

and a pagination constructor

```
this.Pages = new Meteor.Pagination("collection-name", 
    {...
     // you can configure here lots of options
    }
);
```

I actually checked the [examples on the code](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages/blob/master/examples/table/main.coffee) to learn more about the parameters that can be used for customization, but I wasn't able to learn how to manipulate values form the records. To be more clear, I have

```
    fields = ["username", "_id", "firstname", ???];
    headers = ["Submitter", "UID", "First Name", "Custom"];
    this.Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(MyCollection, {
      templateName : 'feedbackListTable',
      table : {
        class: "table",
        fields : fields,
        header : headers,
        wrapper: "table-wrapper"
      }
    });
```

Where I have have the `???` I would like to have the manipulation or transformation of some values like

```
firstname.trim(); //being firstname a value of my document
if(age < 10) return "minor"; //being age a value of the record
<button id="buttonWithID" name={{_id}}>UID</button>
```

If such customization of the values displayed is possible, how can it be achieved? I have (unsuccessfully) tried using functions in the `fields` array and overwriting/declaring them as helpers for the "pages" template. I tried looking for further information, but apart from this site and the github pages I couldn't find much.